# Write to File NullPointerException

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception

Here's my writeToFile() method:

```
public void writeToFile(String string){
    x.format("%s", string);
}
```

And this is how I use this method:

```
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        string = tekstPole.getText();
        tekstLabel.setText(string);
        f.writeToFile(string);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Files.readFile(Files.java:30)
>       at Bicycle.(Bicycle.java:34)
>       at Hristijan.main(Hristijan.java:10)

What could be the problem?

Comment: Provide the code at `Bycicle.java:34` (which is where the variable with `null` value is).

Comment: You need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: _When I try to compile_ No. An **Exception** is something you get at runtime.

Comment: @user3330053 what is the specific line 30 of Files.java?  It seems you are trying to invoke a method on a null instance of a class.  You have to figure out which instance is null and fix that.